# iOS - UITextView pasting weird behavior

Tags: ios, text, uitextview, paste

I have an expandable UITextView, everything works fine except pasting. If the text pasted is longer than maximum height expected. I dont see some part of the text. Only happens with Pasting, and only when the text is longer than maximum height. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard to say what you're doing wrong or right if you don't show what you're doing. What's the code that makes the text view expandable?

Comment: You could truncate the pasted text so it isn't too long.